# How to copy outgoing messages to another address in Exchange Server

Tags: exchange-server

Is it possible to configure Exchange Server to send one copy of outgoing messages of a specific email account to another account?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to record all the communications pertaining to a mailbox,try journaling in exchange server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998649(v=exchg.150).aspx